# collect all elements and indices of an array in two separate arrays in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

Suppose I have an array `array = [1,2,3,4,5]`

I want to collect all the elements and indices of the array in 2 separate arrays like

```ruby
[[1,2,3,4,5], [0,1,2,3,4]]
```

How do I do this using a single Ruby collect statement?

I am trying to do it using this code

```ruby
array.each_with_index.collect do |v,k|
  # code
end
```

What should go in the code section to get the desired output?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" along with the linked pages, and "[mcve]". We'd like to see evidence of your effort, not just a bare outline of the code block. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592 helps explain it.

Comment: Another way: `[arr, Array.new(arr.size, &:itself)]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or even simpler:

```
[array, array.each_index.to_a]
```

Answer (score 1):

I like the first answer that was posted a while ago. Don't know why the guy deleted it.

```ruby
array.each_with_index.collect { |value, index| [value,index] }.transpose
```

Actually I am using an custom vector class on which I am calling the `each_with_index` method.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one simple way:

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5]
indexes = *array.size.times
p [ array, indexes ]
# => [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

See it on repl.it: https://repl.it/FmWg